# JavaScript Mouse Over Pause

Tags: javascript, css, web, mouseover

I am really getting frustrated with my JS slideshow, I am trying to implement a mouse-over pause function in the slideshow. All I need the slideshow to do is pause when the user hovers over the slide. Seems easy right?! No, I have tried incorporating different functions but nothing seems to stick with the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
var imgs1 = new Array("http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/CMS_XMAS_BANNER_2.jpg","http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Dymo_XTL_Range.jpg","http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Banners/Homepage_Banners/Promotional_Banners/Fluke_Cashback_Upgrade_1.jpg","http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Fluke_DTX_Buy_Back_2015.jpg");
var lnks1 = new Array("http://www.cmsplc.com/christmas-opening-times","http://www.cmsplc.com/dymo-xtl","http://www.cmsplc.com/fluke-dsx-upgrade-sept-2015/","http://www.cmsplc.com/fluke-networks-dtx-upgrade-offer/");
var alt1 = new Array();
var currentAd1 = 0;
var imgCt1 = 4;
function cycle1() {
if (currentAd1 == imgCt1) {
currentAd1 = 0;
}
var banner1 = document.getElementById('adBanner1');
var link1 = document.getElementById('adLink1');
banner1.src=imgs1[currentAd1]
banner1.alt=alt1[currentAd1]
document.getElementById('adLink1').href=lnks1[currentAd1]
currentAd1++;
}
window.setInterval("cycle1()",4000);
// ]]></script>
<p><a id="adLink1" target="_top"><img id="adBanner1" src="http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/CMS_XMAS_BANNER_2.jpg" border="0" alt="" width="804" height="300" /></a></p>
```

Where abouts in the above will I need to include the pause functions??!

Comment: Did you see my answer? You can reply to comments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few changes. Give it this way:

```
// Put this on top.
var intvl = 0;

// Replace the setInterval line.
intvl = window.setInterval("cycle1()",4000);
```

And add this event handler:

```
// Add this at the end, may be before `<body />` inside a `<script>` tag.
adBanner1.onmouseover = function () {
  clearInterval(intvl);
}
adBanner1.onmouseout = function () {
  intvl = window.setInterval("cycle1()",4000);
}
```

**Full Code**

```
<p><a id="adLink1" target="_top"><img id="adBanner1" src="http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/CMS_XMAS_BANNER_2.jpg" border="0" alt="" width="804" height="300" /></a></p>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
  var imgs1 = new Array("http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/CMS_XMAS_BANNER_2.jpg","http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Dymo_XTL_Range.jpg","http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Banners/Homepage_Banners/Promotional_Banners/Fluke_Cashback_Upgrade_1.jpg","http://www.cmsplc.com/media/wysiwyg/Fluke_DTX_Buy_Back_2015.jpg");
  var lnks1 = new Array("http://www.cmsplc.com/christmas-opening-times","http://www.cmsplc.com/dymo-xtl","http://www.cmsplc.com/fluke-dsx-upgrade-sept-2015/","http://www.cmsplc.com/fluke-networks-dtx-upgrade-offer/");
  var alt1 = new Array();
  var currentAd1 = 0;
  var imgCt1 = 4;
  var intvl = 0;

  function cycle1() {
    if (currentAd1 == imgCt1) {
      currentAd1 = 0;
    }
    var banner1 = document.getElementById('adBanner1');
    var link1 = document.getElementById('adLink1');
    banner1.src=imgs1[currentAd1]
    banner1.alt=alt1[currentAd1]
    document.getElementById('adLink1').href=lnks1[currentAd1]
    currentAd1++;
  }

  intvl = window.setInterval("cycle1()",4000);

  adBanner1.onmouseover = function () {
    clearInterval(intvl);
  }
  adBanner1.onmouseout = function () {
    intvl = window.setInterval("cycle1()",4000);
  }
  // ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Praveen, can you include the changes into the code I posted? I'm finding it difficult to identify where your recommendations should go...

Comment: You are a life safer Praveen, thank you so much! I'll be sure to spread your name around the community for quality advice and help. Thank you again!

Comment: @WebLad No worries, I just helped you. `:)`

Comment: Hi @PraveenKumar I hope you are well. I have had many comments about the mouse over function on the banner, with the majority being positive. One quick question, when I initially go on the first banner in the list, the link to the webpage does not work. For the link to work I have to move my mouse off the banner and then back on. Is there an alteration to the above code that can be made to allow the link to be clicked as soon as someone goes on the website? Kind regards, James

Comment: @WebLad Lemme have a look.

Comment: @WebLad Looks like your CSS is blocking the way. So may be you need to check your CSS?

Comment: Hi @PraveenKumar, not sure what you mean, have tried re-arranging and formatting code and to no avail. :(

Comment: @WebLad No no... Some other CSS rule is affecting that.